# No puedo hacer funcionar el servidor apache2 en debian12

Tags: php, servidor, apache2

Acabo de instalar en mi notebook Debian 12, apache2, php y mysql, en el archivo 000-default.conf cambie:
DocumentRoot /var/www/html  por
DocumentRoot /home/claudio/www

Tengo en esa ruta un proyecto en php newsyscon.
al poner en el navegador http://localhost sale el siguiente error:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Apache/2.4.57 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80

Cambie los permisos de la carpeta, cree un archivo .htaccess y sigo con el inconveniente, tengo un pc con debian 11 y funciona bien en la misma ruta y funcionan todos los proyectos que ahí tengo,
Será que en Debian 12 hay que hacer algo mas?

Comment: en general es menos engorroso crear un symlink en /var/www que apunte a un /home/scripts/proyecto1 que andar configurando grupos y permisos de tu user home. en el caso de debian12 lo que te estaría faltando es posiblemente configurar el apparmor para que le deje al apache usar la nueva carpeta, fijate en `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/web-data` ( `htpd` `www` o similar ) que dice y le agregas ahi las folders nuevas

Comment: yo usaria el tutorial: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10s_Y4sc_1WSPpm3uDeHv0iBw0XstFLE3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: estoy trabajando en una nuevo para actualizarlos